# CentOS Vagrant Image : Where can I find the public key when login?

Tags: vagrant, centos7

I am installing CentOS Vagrant Images for virtualbox v1708.01(https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7)

When I login with Xshell, it need public key,where can I find the public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the `private_key` file under `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox` folder where you have `Vagrantfile`